# vim make window immutable

Tags: vim, nerdtree, vim-airline

I've recently switched to `vim` and installed the `airline` and `NERDTree` plugins. This combo works nice, displaying the tree in its own window and putting opened files in buffers.

When the `NERDTree` window is focused, right-clicking on the buffer "buttons", which `airline` comes with out-of-the box, the window content gets replaced by the buffer content, e.g. shows the file content.

Is there a way to make the window immutable and reserved for `NERDTree` only?

Comment: What do you mean by `right-clicking`? You're using mouse?

Comment: @Nurzhan yes, accidentally. Don't kill me.

Comment: If you've decided to use vim, then forget about the mouse. However, I still don't get what buffer buttons you mean ))).

Comment: If you want to prevent a buffer's contents from being modified, `:set nomodifiable`.

Comment: @Nurzhan the first sentence actually provides you with some extra info (I'm in my vim infancy still). `airline` comes with a top bar that holds opened buffers.

Comment: @sitilge, Have you resolved your problem? I checked in my vim setup. Nothing like this happens to me.

Comment: MichaelFoukarakis after ```:set nomodifiable``` all off vim is readonly, However ```:setlocal nonmodifiable``` works as advertised.